# Implementing a different ML method to an existing ML tutorial

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, lightgbm

I am very new to python and hoping you guys can help me out.
I am currently reproducing this [tutorial](https://github.com/sentinel-hub/eo-learn/blob/master/examples/land-cover-map/SI_LULC_pipeline.ipynb)
This tutorial uses LightGBM to do classification as seen here:

```
    # Set up training classes
labels_unique = np.unique(labels_train)

# Set up the model
model = lgb.LGBMClassifier(
    objective='multiclass', 
    num_class=len(labels_unique), 
    metric='multi_logloss'
)

# train the model
model.fit(features_train, labels_train)
```

The model is seen here as LightGBM classifier and I would like to try different scikit classifiers such as SVM or MLP on this data.
Ive tried this:

```
   # Instantiate and evaluate classifier
model = SVC(kernel='linear')

# train the model
model.fit(features_train, labels_train)
```

But it wont work. Any advice/suggestions are very welcome

Comment: It would help if you give the whole code and the error message. Without one of these, we can only make guesses of what is wrong in the code